# If new value and old value is same dont update else update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

How to detect and only update if new and old value are different else don't update

```
Update Student
SET First = @FirstName
WHERE EmpId = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this condition to your `where` clause:

```
UPDATE Student
SET    First = @FirstName
WHERE  First != @FirstName AND EmpId = 1
```

EDIT:
As Kevin Suchlicki pointed out in the comments, if `First` is nullable, `null`s should be handled explicitly:

```
UPDATE Student
SET    First = @FirstName
WHERE  EmpId = 1 AND ((First != @FirstName) OR
                      (First IS NULL AND @FirstName IS NOT NULL) OR
                      (First IS NOT NULL AND @FirstName IS NULL))
```

Comment: Watch out for nulls in the existing data and new data, since NULL != 'John' evaluates to FALSE, preventing an update that you want

Comment: @KevinSuchlicki good point, thanks! Edited it into my answer.

Comment: Update Student
SET FirstName = FirstName
WHERE EmpId = 1

Comment: How to check without parameter if value is coming from another external table

Comment: Update student
 SET FirstName = FirstName
 FROM ExtStudent